# Twitter AnomalyDetection package unable to identify negative anomalies

Tags: r, twitter, time-series, anomaly-detection

I've been trying to use Twitter's [AnomalyDetection](https://github.com/twitter/AnomalyDetection) package to identify data that is suspiciously low, but I have been unable to use the option "direction = 'neg'". When I run the following example (taken from [here](http://rstatistics.net/how-to-detect-breakouts-in-a-time-series-in-r/)), I get only a data.frame with 0 observations, and a NULL result for the plot:

```
devtools::install_github("twitter/AnomalyDetection") # install twitter's AnomalyDetection

library(AnomalyDetection)

library(fpp) # for 'ausair' data

library(lubridate)

myTS <- ausair # initialise data

myPeriod <- "year" # set the period

ymth <- paste(start(myTS), collapse="/")

startDate <- as.Date(paste(ymth, "1", sep="/"), format="%Y/%m/%d") # start date

eymth <- paste(end(myTS), collapse="/")

endDate <- as.Date(paste(eymth, "1", sep="/"), format="%Y/%m/%d") # end date

Dates <- seq.Date(startDate, endDate, by=myPeriod) # create the dates

Dates <- ymd(Dates) # convert to POSIXct

Dates <- as.POSIXct(Dates)

myData <- data.frame(Dates, myTS) # cast as a data.frame

AnomalyDetectionTs(myData, max_anoms = 0.2, direction='pos', plot=TRUE) # this works!

AnomalyDetectionTs(myData, max_anoms = 0.2, direction='neg', plot=TRUE) # this doesn't
```

Is there any way to use the "direction = 'neg'" option?

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer to this might be that there aren't any neg anomalies. I've seen this happen with my analysis. Try relaxing the max_anoms parameter and your model would become more sensitive to them.